# C++ and my global variable for mouse class

Tags: c++, global-variables, scope, extern

I'm so stuck, it's so annoying... I have windows message sending mouse coordinates and I have a game loop that sees those coordinates, but when I call upon a class that looks at the mouse coordinates, it can't see the mouse coordinates, it just creates its own version of the mouse regardless of me defining a global.h and referencing extern on the .cpp file that's using it:

**Mouse.h**

```
#pragma once

class Mouse
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    void MouseMove( int x, int y );
    Mouse();
};
```

**Global.h**

```
#include "Mouse.h"

static Mouse mouse;
```

**Game.cpp //snippet of code//**

```
Game::Game( HWND hWnd, Mouse &mouse  )
    :
    gfx( hWnd ),
    mouse( mouse )
{
...
if( scenes[ a ]->interactiveObjects[ b ]->CheckCollision( mouse.x, mouse.y ) )
{
.... // Game is looping if no messages stored, the windows loop updates my mouse coordinates by calling a routine in my Mouse.cpp. My windows loop sends the mouse through as a parameter to my game object which I no longer want to use... I want to use my global mouse as the mouse reference.
```

"InteractiveObject.cpp" it contains the "Global.h" and references the mouse declared in it... right? So why does my check collision not see the mouse.x and mouse.y (I have to pass the coordinates in from my game object as paramteres mouseX and mouseY :(

```
#include "Global.h"
extern Mouse mouse;

#include "InteractiveObject.h"


InteractiveObject::InteractiveObject(  int id_, string title_, Image* theImage_, int type_, int x_, int y_, int z_ )
    : 
    id( id_ ),
    title( title_ ),
    theImage( theImage_ ),
    type( type_ ),
    x( x_ ),
    y( y_ ),
    z( z_ )
{
    pos.x = x_;
    pos.y = y_;
    pos.z = z_;
}

bool InteractiveObject::CheckCollision( int mouseX, int mouseY )
{
    if( 
        mouse.x > x &&
        mouse.x < x + theImage->width &&
        mouse.y > y &&
        mouse.y < y + theImage->height
    )   
    /*if( 
        mouseX > x &&
        mouseX < x + theImage->width &&
        mouseY > y &&
        mouseY < y + theImage->height
    )*/
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: why do you have a local `mouse` object in the game?

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of it now :D by making a global mouse... I have already removed the game parameter from my game class, ofcourse none of my game can now see the globally defined mouse. Am I using extern wrong? @Dave

Comment: You need to remove the local variable or give it a different name, because at the moment any changes to `mouse` within the `game` object will change the *local* copy, not the *global* one.

Comment: @Dave, I removed the instance from the game class constructor etc... I now am just using the extern technique, but now my game cannot see the mouse at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your global.h header you should have

```
extern Mouse mouse;
```

In one place in your code (and one place only) at file scope in an implementation file, you should have the line below. InteractiveObject.cpp works ok for this.

```
Mouse mouse;
```

This way, global.h promises any file unit that includes it that a mouse variable of type Mouse exists somewhere. The "Mouse mouse" line actually allocates that instance.

There are architectural implications of doing it this way, but it'll work. The way you had it, any implementation file that includes global.h would have created it's own local instance of "mouse" that was a different instance than any other. While the extern Mouse... line promised the linker that somewhere "mouse" existed at global scope.

Comment: Can't say thank you enough by the way. That really got me moving on with my project... Cheers @Digikata and everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

Your global.h is being expanded into each file you include it in. So there's a static (meaning this file only) instantiation of the global for each file you include it in. Try using the singleton pattern or declaring the variable as extern in the header and then once in mouse.cpp

Comment: Beautiful person... you have unleashed the fury of my game.. roarrrr. Thanks to everyone else btw!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of singletons, but in the interest of reigning in your bugs for the time being...

Make it a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

```
class Mouse
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    void MouseMove( int x, int y );
    static Mouse & get_mouse()
    {
        static Mouse m;
        return m;
    }
private:
    // Inaccessible outside of Mouse!
    Mouse();
    Mouse( const Mouse & );
};
```

Now your code will need to call `Mouse::get_mouse()` to get the one-and-only `Mouse`.

You will now be assured that additional instances of `Mouse` are not accidentally created anywhere.  Your compiler will stop you if it happens.